# UIView inputView vs inputViewController

Tags: ios, ios7, ios8, autolayout, custom-keyboard

In iOS7 or earlier, I could simply set the `inputView` property of `UIView` in order to implement a custom keyboard within my app. When the device would rotate, I would simply reset the `inputView`'s frame's height to the landscape or portrait keyboard's height, and the keyboard height would update properly.

In iOS8, all of this is broken. Changes to the `inputView`'s frame are simply ignored. I've tried adjusting the `inputView`'s autoresizing mask and autolayout constraints, but these also fail in other ways.

Is it now required to subclass `UIInputViewController` and `UIInputView` in order to implement a custom keyboard (even when it's not a system-wide keyboard)? I can't find anything in Apple's documentation that supports this, but it appears it may be the case.

Comment: I am not sure that must be the approach for a Custom keyboard in iOS 8 as Apple has now provided a provision to have your custom keyboard through Extensions. You can design a full fletched keyboard with that approach.

Comment: have you figured this out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The keyboard height issue is an iOS8 bug, and subclassing UIInputViewController will not fix it. The purpose of UIInputViewController is solely for doing system-wide keyboards, and as Apple states [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/Keyboard.html), you shouldn't use it if you are doing a custom keyboard for your own app, only.

> Make sure a custom, systemwide keyboard is indeed what you want to
>   develop. To provide a fully custom keyboard for just your app or to
>   supplement the system keyboard with custom keys in just your app, the
>   iOS SDK provides other, better options. Read about custom input views
>   and input accessory views in Custom Views for Data Input in Text
>   Programming Guide for iOS.

Ultimately, I was forced to develop my own iOS8 solution by ditching the iOS system keyboard and building out a structure that mimics the system keyboard by creating my own keyboard view structure, animating it in/out, writing custom code to respond to system events that normally dismiss the keyboard, etc. This is a very horrible and costly bug for Apple to have allowed into iOS8, especially when custom keyboards were supposed to be one of the great new things in iOS8.

Comment: This is not true. Using UIInputViewController for a keyboard or other input view that will appear only within your app is perfectly fine. And it solves the size problem; for example, the keyboard's height can be set (and changed) from the inside out with constraints.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it now required to subclass UIInputViewController and UIInputView in order to implement a custom keyboard (even when it's not a system-wide keyboard)?

I don't know whether it's required, but it is certainly recommended to subclass UIInputViewController if you intend to make a custom keyboard within your app. In fact, Apple recommends this as a first step if you're planning to make a keyboard extension: first do it as an internal keyboard and test it in that form, and it's then easy to migrate that into a keyboard extension if you wish.

You do *not* subclass UIInputView under those circumstances; you use the input view vended by the input view controller.

This completely solves the problem you're having, because the view controller *is a view controller* and gets the standard view controller events related to rotation and layout. Moreover, the input view can be laid out internally using autolayout constraints, so that your layout remains coherent as the keyboard is resized.